# Creating a dynamic array of boxes in listview in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-layout

I am really confused as per what should I do, I am pretty bad with the layout of flutter.

I want to create boxes in the listview according to the number of strings (addresses) I have in another class - what is the best practice or approach for that?

[Here Is the Image of the APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIeM1.jpg)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

import 'AddData.dart';
import 'package:donation_yoga/services/json_service.dart';

//import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  /* Getting Live Location */
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();

  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPos = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: latLngPos, zoom: 15.0);

    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          myLayoutWidget(),
          _buildContainer(),
          _createForm(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myLayoutWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          locatePosition();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildContainer() {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 150.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO3VPL9m-b355xWeg4MXmOQTauFAEkavSluTtJU=w225-h160-k-no",
                40.738380,
                -73.988426,
                Centres.first),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMKRN-1zTYMUVPrH-CcKzfTo6Nai7wdL7D8PMkt=w340-h160-k-no",
                40.761421,
                -73.981667,
                Centres.second),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504940892017-d23b9053d5d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                40.732128,
                -73.999619,
                Centres.third),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat, double long, String restaurantName) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      child: new FittedBox(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 14.0,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 180,
                  height: 200,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                    child: Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: NetworkImage(_image),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: myDetailsContainer1(restaurantName),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget myDetailsContainer1(String restaurantName) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: Container(
            child: Text(
          restaurantName,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff6200ee),
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: Text(
            "4.1",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          )),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStarHalf,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              child: Text(
            "(946)",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          )),
        ],
      )),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Text(
        "This is ",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      )),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Text(
        "Closed \u00B7 Opens 17:00 Thu",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      )),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _createForm(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment(-0.2, -1.0),
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddData()),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Create")),
  );
}
```

Here is my Other Class.

```
class Centres {
  static const String first = 'This is our first location';
  static const String second = 'This is our Second location';
  static const String third = 'This is our Third locations';
}
```

The data in this class is gonna come from server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListView.builder to create a list of your boxes, just provide an `item count` that means how many widgets it will create and use the `index` to access each value you want to take from the lists of values.

I know i did not use you `Centres class`, unless you really need it to be a class, i find it easier to use a list with the values you need

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
    final List<String> centres = [
      'first location',
      'second location',
      'third location'
    ];
    final List<double> latitudes = [40.732128, 40.732128, 40.732128];
    final List<double> longitudes = [-73.999619, -73.999619, -73.999619];

    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _boxes(
            entries[index],
            latitudes[index],
            longitudes[index],
            centres[index],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I have removed the _buildcontainer widget and myDetailsContainer1 Widget and pasted your code removing the classing and renaming just the widget to listWidget1()?

Displays nothing on screen

Comment: ~final List<String> centres = [
  'first location',
  'second location',
  'third location'
];
final List<double> latitudes = [40.732128, 40.732128, 40.732128];
final List<double> longitudes = [-73.999619, -73.999619, -73.999619];

Widget listWidget1() {
  return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _boxes(
          entries[index],
          latitudes[index],
          longitudes[index],
          centres[index],
        );
      });
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use both ListView.builder() and PageView.builder(). in ListView you can stay in between two boxes but PageView only stays on one box. both have the itemCount and itemBuilder.